# While loop execute twice in one function call

Tags: c++, windows, forms, while-loop

I have a problem with the while loop, I have instructed that the key1 variable should only be executed when at least some "if" instructions have been executed, however, it re-executes the while loop even if the variable key1 is equal to 0.
It should be noted that I do not change the value of the key1 variable in another part of the function

```
void form_table(...) {

int key1=1;

while (key1 != 0)  <==(2)
{
    key1=0;                 
    if (dx->get_numero() == 1 && dy->get_numero() == 1)
    {
     key1++;

    //Some code
    }

    else if (dx->get_numero() == 1 && dy->get_numero() == 0)
       {
        key1++;
        //some code     
       }
    else if (dx->get_numero() == 0 && dy->get_numero() == 1)
       {
           key1++;
               //some code
       } <==(1)
    else
       break;//I put it in case, but even with that it goes back into the buble while

}


}//Here is the problem, when finish the funcion execution the program comes back to the line (1), and then re-runs the while cycle (2)
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: This is a good example of *spaghetti code*. Rewrite it. The goal should be to avoid all 'else' branches if possible. Have a look at the Select Case statement.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, *watching* values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting to StackOverflow and **waiting** for someone else to inspect or debug your program for you.

Answer (score 1):

the loop works if key1 is different from 0 if you increment key1 and therefore it is different from 0 the cycle reinitiates.

you have to do:

```
while (key1 == 0) {
     // rest of the code
}
```